# VBA Loop along a row

Tags: vba, loops

Is it possible to loop along a row?

I have a header row of dates, I want to loop through those dates and if one of the dates is earlier than todays date I want an action to copy the content of the cells below and paste the values to override the formulas in that column.

I've done loops down a column before but I'm really struggling doing it along a row. any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Almost same thing, just change the number of column in loop and keep same number of row. Try that and show us your code attempts :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods to examine cells in a range

1  If you know the size you can use For Each

```
   Dim r as range
   For each r in Range("A1:F1")
       'r is assigned to each cell in range above in turn
   Next r
```

(Or if the user highlights the range before hand you can use the Selection Property)

```
  For each r in Selection
```

2  Or You can loop through using a For Next and Cells

```
    Dim x as long
    For x = 1 to 6
     If Cells(1,x) = "Some Value" Then
     End If
    Next x
```

3  If you don't know the  end and just want to go till the next blank cell then use a Do Loop

```
   Dim r as Range
   Set r = Range("A1")
   Do
      'something
       Set r = r.Offset(0,1)  'move pointer right
    Loop Until r = ""
```

Hope this helps